# Trouble Grabbing HTML variable using python scraping

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code is meant to scrape data variables from a website and plot the values down. I am trying to use this so that I can graph the prices of graphics cards over time.

I am using beautifulsoup and everything is working, except I can't get the price to properly print.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://www.newegg.ca/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007708%20601210955%20601203901%20601294835%20601295933%20601194948&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&Order=BESTSELLING&PageSize=96"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

filename = "GPU Prices.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

header = "Price,Product Brand,Product Name,Shipping Cost\n"

f.write(header)

for container in containers:
    price_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-current"})
    price = price_container[0].text.strip()

    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

    price
    f.write(price.replace(",", "") + "," + brand.replace(",", ".") + "," +  product_name.replace(",", " |") + "," +  shipping + "\n")

f.close()
```

After running this, the csv file looks like this:

[image: CSV output format]

Comment: What do you mean by price is not printing properly? You do not want to print the available offers? or formatting them in the excel?

Comment: If you see attached screenshot, the prices bar skips lines with entries such as "-" and "|". Rather than being all uniform, it creates extra lines and so everything lines up but the cost doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Python CSV library to help with writing your file. A `csv.writer()` object takes a list of items will automatically add the commas between your items and if any item has a comma in it, it will automatically wrap the entry in quotes (which is the correct way to handle them). The file would then load correctly.

Also, your `price` variable needed a bit of trimming as it contained a number of trailing characters that needed to first be removed.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

my_url = "https://www.newegg.ca/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007708%20601210955%20601203901%20601294835%20601295933%20601194948&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&Order=BESTSELLING&PageSize=96"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})
filename = "GPU Prices.csv"
header = ['Price', 'Product Brand', 'Product Name', 'Shipping Cost']

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for container in containers:
        price_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-current"})
        price = price_container[0].text.replace('\xa0', ' ').strip(' –\r\n|')

        brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

        title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
        product_name = title_container[0].text

        shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
        shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

        csv_output.writerow([price, brand, product_name, shipping])
```

Giving you `GPU Prices.csv` starting as:

```
Price,Product Brand,Product Name,Shipping Cost
"$1,079.99 (5 Offers)",ASUS,ASUS ROG GeForce GTX 1080 Ti DirectX 12 STRIX-GTX1080TI-O11G-GAMING 11GB 352-Bit GDDR5X PCI Express 3.0 HDCP Ready Video Card,$4.99 Shipping
$794.99 (5 Offers),ASUS,ASUS ROG GeForce GTX 1080 STRIX-GTX1080-A8G-GAMING 8GB 256-Bit GDDR5X PCI Express 3.0 HDCP Ready Video Card,$4.99 Shipping
```

See how the second row price does not contain a comma, so is not enclosed in quotes. This is correct and will be handled correctly by an application such as Excel.